# Flutter build results in error about app signing when building for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, provisioning-profile

I am trying to build my flutter app for iOS using the command *flutter build ios*.

When I do so, it fails with the following error...

```
error: No profiles for 'com.me.myapp' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.me.myapp'. Automatic
    signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

When I open the runner project in xcode, the automatic signing check box is already checked.

I do not have a physical device, so I can not create a provisioning profile. I was previously able to build this app on iOS, and I am not sure exactly what changed.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Comment: Do you have a distribution provisioning profile with the app id called ```com.me.myapp``` in the apple developer portal?

Comment: No I do not. Must I? I do not plan on distributing yet.

Comment: Try unchecking the automatic signing and check it again.